# Why RunOnUiThread is throwing an exception in Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, exception, xamarin.android

I am using a timer in my Android app (programming in `c#`) which edits the text of `TextView` each time the timer is fired so I need to use `RunOnUiThread`.

```
    TextView text;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            text = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView4);
     _timer.Interval = 100;
            _timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            _timer.Start();
      }
    private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            this.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
             text.Text += "bm";

        });
         }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
      }
```

In every first launch of my app, when the `OnTimedEvent` method is called an unhanded exception is thrown without any details and the `Toast` message is not showing which means the `catch` is not called. But in the second launch everything is okay and the `OnTimedEvent` method is being called fine.
I have tried to remove the `RunOnUiThread` and no exception was thrown but also the `text.Text` wasn't updated. 
Why is that happening ?

**Edit**

Stacktrace:

> 12-25 17:06:20.847 W/GAv4    (13655): CampaignTrackingReceiver is not
>   registered, not exported or is disabled. Installation campaign
>   12-25 17:06:20.987 W/System.err(13655): remove failed: ENOENT (No such
>   file or directory) :
>   /data/user/0/dabboussi.RandomG/shared_prefs/com.google.android.gms.analytics.prefs.xml.bak
>   12-25 17:06:21.342 D/SecWifiDisplayUtil(13655): Metadata value : none
>   12-25 17:06:21.352 D/ViewRootImpl(13655): #1 mView =
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{16fd198 I.E......
>   R.....ID 0,0-0,0} 12-25 17:06:21.782 D/ViewRootImpl(13655):
>   MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
>   12-25 17:06:22.067 I/Timeline(13655): Timeline: Activity_idle id:
>   android.os.BinderProxy@9d3df7b time:234415682 12-25 17:06:27.567
>   D/ViewRootImpl(13655): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0 12-25
>   17:06:27.657 D/ViewRootImpl(13655): ViewPostImeInputStage
>   processPointer 1 12-25 17:06:28.092 D/ViewRootImpl(13655):
>   MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1012) or=1 12-25
>   17:06:30.997 D/ViewRootImpl(13655): The input has been finished in
>   ImeInputStage. 12-25 17:06:31.062 D/ViewRootImpl(13655): The input has
>   been finished in ImeInputStage. 12-25 17:06:31.102
>   D/ViewRootImpl(13655): MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0,
>   96 - 0, 0) or=1 12-25 17:06:32.482 D/ViewRootImpl(13655):
>   ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0 12-25 17:06:32.567
>   D/ViewRootImpl(13655): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1 Loaded
>   assembly: System.dll [External] 12-25 17:06:32.642 I/Timeline(13655):
>   Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:dabboussi.RandomG time:234426256
>   Thread started:  #2 12-25 17:06:33.082 D/SecWifiDisplayUtil(13655):
>   Metadata value : none 12-25 17:06:33.082 D/ViewRootImpl(13655): #1
>   mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{e762cd
>   I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0} Thread started:  #3 Thread
>   started:  #4 Thread started:  #5 Thread
>   started:  #6 Thread started:  #7 12-25
>   17:06:33.142 D/ViewRootImpl(13655): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96
>   - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1 Thread started:  #8 Thread started:  #9 Thread started:  #10
>   Thread started:  #11 Thread started:  #12
>   Thread started:  #13 An unhandled exception occured.

Comment: Does `text` var initialized properly?

Comment: Yes it is. The problem is with `RunOnUiThread`.

Comment: Note if the exception occurs inside the target of `RunOnUiThread` (in this case the anonymous implementation of `text.Text +=...` ) then try-catch as you have it will not catch it (because it is a different thread) - in this case,  most likely your exception is the  `text` field is null.  Put a try-catch inside the anonymous implementation for debug purposes and proceed from there.

Comment: I tried to put the `try catch` inside the `RunOnUiThread` it did not threw any exception so I am confident that the `RunOnUiThread` is causing the exception. Is there an alternative or a workarround for `RunOnUiThread` ? @Andy

Comment: What is the full exception/stacktrace?

Comment: Check my update please. @SushiHangover

Comment: I don't know what CampaignTrackingReceiver is. It is not a class of my app.

Comment: You can also try catching `Throwable` instead of Exception so that it includes the other 2 subclasses (which normally are unnecessary to handle) just to exclude this as a possibility.